# CakePHP patchEntity not saving data ("through" association)

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm new to CakePHP and have been using the CakePHP cookbook and stackoverflow to try to solve my issue but couldn't. It's probably something silly.

I have Quotes, Items and the jointable with joindata QuotesItems.

I have this in my edit.ctp (template Quotes):

```
<div class="quotes form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($quote) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Edit Quote') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', ['options' => $customers]);
            echo $this->Form->input('items._ids', ['options' => $items]);
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($quote['items'] as $item):
            echo $this->Form->input( "items.$counter.description", array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' ) );
            echo $this->Form->input("items.$counter._joinData.item_quantity");
            $counter++;
        endforeach
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

In the QuotesController I have for edit function:

```
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $quote = $this->Quotes->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Items']
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $quote = $this->Quotes->patchEntity($quote, $this->request->data, ['Quotes._joinData']);
            //$quote = $this->Quotes->patchEntity($quote, $this->request->data, ['associated'=>['QuotesItems'=>['associated'=>['Items']]]] );
            if ($this->Quotes->save($quote)) {
debug($this->request->data);
                $this->Flash->success(__('The quote has been saved.'));

                //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The quote could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $customers = $this->Quotes->Customers->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $items = $this->Quotes->Items->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('quote', 'customers', 'items'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['quote']);
    }
```

The array sent when the form is saved is:

```
[
    'customer_id' => '1',
    'items' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '1'
        ],
        (int) 0 => [
            '_joinData' => [
                'item_quantity' => '18'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I've checked the saving "Saving data" of the cookbook but it didn't clear up what I'm doing wrong.

Does the data need the ID of the quote? Is the way I'm iterating over the items correct?

The Table associations are made as follows:
Quotes:

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Items', [
        'through' => 'QuotesItems'
    ]);
```

Items:

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Quotes', [
        'through' => 'QuotesItems'
    ]);
```

QuotesItems (jointable):

```
    $this->belongsTo('Quotes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'quote_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Items', [
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try making array format something like this:

```
[
 'customer_id' => '1',
 'items' => [
    'id' => 1, // this is primary key of items table
    'item_quantity' => '18' // this is another field of items table
    ]
]
```

And in your edit method use commented line:

```
$quote = $this->Quotes->patchEntity($quote, $this->request->data, ['associated'=>['QuotesItems'=>['associated'=>['Items']]]] );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I put the line you mention in the controller I get an exception 'Cannot marshal data for "QuoteItems" association. It is not associated with "Quotes".' Apart from that I'm surprised that cakePhp can't handle such a "basic" scenario by using the cake bake command and that I would have to fiddle to modify the data (I can understand in different scenarios but this seems a basic). Although cakephp has a lot of documentation this is not really explained clearly.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I see that you're having ID immediately under items. And item_quantity as well. Shouldn't this been nested in _joinData? I do have a primary key for the jointable so I would expect it to be necesary in the data as well? thanks in advance.

Comment: Ya if the tables are in proper relations that works without nested in _joinData. I have checked it before , and works well.

Comment: if such things get harder then deleting and re-inserting may be the better option as well.

Comment: "Ya if the tables are in proper relations that works without nested in _joinData. I have checked it before , and works well."

Comment: So what would be wrong with the relations? I have the definitions as in my initial post. Or is there a chance that something else is failing (like validationrules) and the actual update of the database is never really executed? I think I've seen some errors when I print_r some objects. It's mentioning that some values can't be empty (of the entity Item). While I only want to update the joindata (and want to prevent changes to Item entity). And it seems that after adding those mentioned Item attributes(and adding the id of QuotesItems entity in the joindata) to the form the save is working.

Comment: ya you should check there if errors occur..using debug() is better that print_r in cakephp..

Comment: I had my tables in a correct relationship, but the update on joinData only worked if I included the join table's id too.